# How to compile Fable.JsonConverter

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I'd like to use Fable.JsonConverter.

My test code (almost copy [this](http://fable.io/docs/interacting.html#json-serialization)) `FableJson.fs` is below,

```
module FableJson

open Newtonsoft.Json

// Always use the same instance of the converter
// as it will create a cache to improve performance
let private jsonConverter = Fable.JsonConverter() :> JsonConverter

// Serialization
let toJson value =
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, [|jsonConverter|])

// Deserialization
let ofJson<'T> json =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'T>(json, [|jsonConverter|])
```

and `paket.dependencies` file added nuget Fable.JsonConverter

```
source https://nuget.org/api/v2
storage:none

clitool dotnet-fable
nuget Fable.Core
nuget Fable.Import.Browser
nuget Fable.JsonConverter
```

and `src/paket.references` file added Fable.JsonConverter

```
dotnet-fable
Fable.Core
Fable.Import.Browser
Fable.JsonConverter
```

**But cannnot compile.**

```
~~~ snip ~~~
ERROR in ./src/FableJson.fs
d:/SRC/Repos/Fable/testJsonConverter/src/FableJson.fs(11,4): (11,57) error FABLE: Cannot find replacement for Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert::SerializeObject
 @ ./src/App.fs 6:0-48
 @ ./src/testJsonConverter.fsproj
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/testJsonConverter.fsproj

ERROR in ./src/FableJson.fs
d:/SRC/Repos/Fable/testJsonConverter/src/FableJson.fs(15,4): (15,62) error FABLE: Cannot find replacement for Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert::DeserializeObject
 @ ./src/App.fs 6:0-48
 @ ./src/testJsonConverter.fsproj
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/testJsonConverter.fsproj

ERROR in ./src/FableJson.fs
d:/SRC/Repos/Fable/testJsonConverter/src/FableJson.fs(7,28): (7,49) error FABLE: Cannot find replacement for Fable.JsonConverter::.ctor
 @ ./src/App.fs 6:0-48
 @ ./src/testJsonConverter.fsproj
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/testJsonConverter.fsproj
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Maslow is right, with Fable 2 we removed Fable.JsonConverter in favour of the library created by the community.

- [Thoth.Json](https://thoth-org.github.io/Thoth.Json/) offers an Elm-like experience where you can decode the JSON manually or automatically depending on your preference. This library also offers a good error message
- [Fable.SimpleJson](https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Fable.SimpleJson) a library for parsing and transforming JSON in Fable projects

Thoth.Json is complemented with Thoth.Json.Net to allow you to use the same API on the backend.

I think Fable.SimpleJson also offer supports for the backend, but I am not sure.

You can use the JavaScript native API `Fable.Core.JS.JSON.stringify` and `Fable.Core.JS.JSON.parse(x)` but you will have to use `unbox`/cast to force the type of your Data which is not safe and can break easily.

Answer (score 3):

See here: http://fable.io/docs/interacting.html#json-serialization

On the client side you should use the `Fable.Core.JsInterop` functions `toJson` and `ofJson`.

`Fable.JsonConverter` is for the server-side only. It uses `Newtonsoft.Json`, which is a .NET library that doesn't run in the browser. The compile error you're getting is because Fable doesn't know how to convert `Newtonsoft.Json` function calls into JavaScript.

It can be confusing when you're working with a language that works in one runtime (e.g. .NET) and also compiles into another one (e.g. JS), but you should try to keep a clear mental model where all of your code is running and therefore what it has access to.

Comment: I see. I could not read the document well.
It is difficult for beginners to know where to read...

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is no longer valid. For newer Fable the only thing I've been able to find is `Fable.Core.JS.JSON.stringify` which calls the browser's built-in serializer.
Also `Fable.Core.JS.JSON.parse(x)` which returns `obj`.